# Script con tablas de multiplicar en php

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando hacer un script en  php que me permita crear las tablas de multiplicar existentes entre dos números elegidos. Por ejemplo entre el 10 y el 20. ¿ Alguna idea?

Gracias

Comment: una simple búsqueda en google con el texto "tabla multiplicar php" en el primer resultado pude obtener exactamente lo que quieres...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así hecho rápido en `$uno` igualas al primer valor y en `$dos` el segundo y `$multiplicarHasta` puse 11 porque en el `for` si pongo 10 que es el máximo en la tabla de multiplicar se hace hasta 9 es solo por eso.
Luego son dos for, en el primer obtienes los números que hay entre `$uno` y `$dos`, y en el segundo a cada uno de sus valores los multiplicas hasta diez:

```
  <style>
    #datos {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    }

   #datos td, #datos th {
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   padding: 8px;
   }

   #datos tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

   #datos tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

   #datos th {
   padding-top: 12px;
   padding-bottom: 12px;
   text-align: left;
   background-color: #4CAF50;
   color: white;
  }
  </style>
  <?php

  $uno = 1;
  $dos = 2;
  $multiplicarHasta = 11;

  for ($i=$uno; $i < ($dos + 1); $i++) { 
   echo "<table id='datos'><tr>";
   echo "<th>Tabla del ".$i."</th></tr>";
   for ($j=1; $j < $multiplicarHasta; $j++) { 
    echo "<tr><td>".$i. " x ".$j." = ".$i * $j."</td></tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
   echo "<br>";
   }
```

Pongo un ejemplo de como los devuelve por que no se todavia como poner codigo que se ejecute aca.
Lo unico que tenes que cambiar para ver otros valores seria el valor de $uno y el valor de $dos (desde -  hasta)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vale muchas gracias. Para anidar tablas para que aparezcan una detras de otra y visualmente aparezca ordenador que función sería en css?

Comment: Ahi acomode para que te muestre la multiplicacion, ahora lo ultimo que me comentas no comprendo, si tenes un print de como queres que se vea y lo subis en tu comentario lo podria ver.

Comment: Sí para que aparezca las tablas ordenadas, por ejemplo como aparece en la última tabla aquí http://elticus.com/?contenido=111